# Why one `colorKey` in `ParticleSystem` cannot be changed without a new Gradient?

Tags: unity, c#

My question is partly a continuation of [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172314/unity-i-cant-change-the-coloroverlifetime-property-of-the-particle-system/172324?noredirect=1#comment338025_172324). So, why I can't change just one `GradientColorKey` this way (without replacing the whole `Gradient` instance):

```
ColorOverLifetimeModule colorOverLifetime = _particle.colorOverLifetime; 
MinMaxGradient color = colorOverLifetime.color; 
color.gradient.colorKeys[1] = new GradientColorKey(new Color(1, 0, 0), 0.5f); 
colorOverLifetime.color = color;
```

[`colorOverLifetime.color`](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/96fb16e2eb6fff1acf3d4e25fa713defb3d17999/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/ParticleSystem.cs#L2090) is [`MinMaxGradient`](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/96fb16e2eb6fff1acf3d4e25fa713defb3d17999/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/ParticleSystem.cs#L832) struct, so I copy its value in a variable `color`.

The `colorOverLifetime.color.gradient` property is [`Gradient`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Gradient.bindings.cs#L59) class and there is no need to copy it.

The `colorKeys` property is just an array of [`GradientColorKey`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Gradient.bindings.cs#L14) struct. So, I assign a new `GradientColorKey` value to the array element that already exists.

Why shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while I was writing this question, I think I found the answer along the way. If you look into the [implementation](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/96fb16e2eb6fff1acf3d4e25fa713defb3d17999/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/ParticleSystem.cs#L2068) of the `ColorOverLifetimeModule` struct `color` property it should be clear why my code doesn't work:

```
  public ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient color
  {
    get
    {
      ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient gradient = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient();
      ParticleSystem.ColorOverLifetimeModule.GetColor(this.m_ParticleSystem, ref gradient);
      return gradient;
    }
    set
    {
      ParticleSystem.ColorOverLifetimeModule.SetColor(this.m_ParticleSystem, ref value);
    }
  }
```

in the getter *they return a reference to a copy* of the `MinMaxGradient` instance.

So, I tried to fix my code this way:

```
ColorOverLifetimeModule colorOverLifetime = _particle.colorOverLifetime;
MinMaxGradient color = colorOverLifetime.color;
var gradient = color.gradient;
gradient.colorKeys[1] = new GradientColorKey(new Color(1, 0, 0), 0.5f);
color.gradient = gradient;
colorOverLifetime.color = color;
```

but this still didn't work. I noticed that `colorKeys[1]` hadn't changed after the assignment. I could find only this piece of implementation of the `Gradient` class `colorKeys[]` property:

```
extern public GradientColorKey[] colorKeys
{
    [FreeFunction("Gradient_Bindings::GetColorKeys", IsThreadSafe = true, HasExplicitThis = true)] get;
    [FreeFunction("Gradient_Bindings::SetColorKeys", IsThreadSafe = true, HasExplicitThis = true)] set;
}
```

so I can't say what's going on in there. Likely, they use the same pattern - return a copy of the array.

If so, it should work this way:

```
ColorOverLifetimeModule colorOverLifetime = _particle.colorOverLifetime;
MinMaxGradient color = colorOverLifetime.color;
var keys = color.gradient.colorKeys;
keys[1] = new GradientColorKey(new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f), middleColor.time);
color.gradient.colorKeys = keys;
colorOverLifetime.color = color;
```

and it really does!

*Summary: we don't need to explicitly recreate the `Gradient`, but we need to copy all these properties to variables and then copy them back.*

**P.S.**
To me this looks like a very unintuitive approach that makes C# developers stumble over such things and spend extra time trying to figure out what's wrong (thanks we've got decompiled Unity sources, otherwise we could only guess). I think methods might be better candidates for such tricks - at least developers won't have certain expectations as they have about properties.